# Git Log Pretty Format - Grab just a number from the title

Tags: git, format, git-log

When we merge code all titles have a pull request number (#500)

Using git log I can grab the title:

```
git log --after=2017-04 --pretty=format:"%s"
```

Which would give me a string like this:

`Adding 5 new features (#500)`

How do I extract only the number contained in (#).

Input:

`git log --after=2017-04 --pretty=format:"foo"`

Output:

`500`

Comment: Use a regular expression with sed, awk, perl, or the tool of your choosing.

Comment: Does --pretty=format just use regex or I should | into awk?

Comment: Pipe it through awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome, seems like easiest way if to just use the output and pipe to a tool and use regex. Thanks @Flimzy

I ended up doing this:

`echo "Adding 5 new features (#500)" | grep -o '#[0-9]\+' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'`